# DataGridTemplateColumn ComboBox not updating row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I've made a small datagrid with two columns:

- DataGridTextColumn
- DataGridTemplateColumn

Attatched is an item in RowValidationRules, which is fired if i change a cell in DataGridTextColumn.

The itemsSource of the DataGrid is an ObservableCollection.
The ComboBox has its own ObservableCollection.

The value in the Combobox associate proper with the corresponding id in the Datagrid.

If i change the Value in the ComboBox, the PropertyChanged handler of the ObservableCollection item is successfuly triggered, but the ValidationRule is not fired.

Only after change the value in the DataGridTextColumn cell, the validation is fired.

Here's the code for the DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
FrameworkElementFactory cbFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));



        cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, CategoriesDropDown);
        cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "CategorieDescription");
        cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Id");
        cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.NameProperty, "cboTest");
        cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding("ParentID") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged});

        cbFactory.AddHandler(ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboChanged));

        DataGridTemplateColumn parentCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
        {
            Header = "Übergeordnete Kategorie",
            CellTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ComboBox)) { VisualTree = cbFactory },
            CellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ComboBox)) { VisualTree = cbFactory },
        };
```

It works as it should with a DataGridComboBoxColumn, but that's not the desired way.

Any suggestions why the PropertyChanged event don't start the validation?

Comment: The CellTemplate  should contain a read-only TextBlock. It is when you edit the ComboBox in the Cell*Editing*ItemTemplate that the update is committed and the ValidationRule should get fired.

Comment: can you give me a short example? Should i put the combobox in a stacklayout or how can i put several items in a TemplateColumn?

Comment: Just set the CellTemplate property to a DataTemplate(typeof(TextBlock)) instead of a DataTemplate(typeof(ComboBox)).

Comment: You're right the validation is triggered now, but to edit the cell, the user needs to click three times. 1) select row 2) select cell 3) open combobox list. Is there another solution that works like the cell with text. 1) select row 2) edit text.

Comment: Yes, that's how a DataGrid works.